# Interpretation of cosine similarity and jaccard similarity (similarity of histograms)

Tags: matlab, histogram, similarity, cosine-similarity, pdist

**Introduction**

I would like to assess the similarity between two "bin counts" arrays (related to two histograms), by using the Matlab "[pdist2](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)" function:

```
% Input
bin_counts_a = [689   430   311   135    66    67    99    23    37    19     8     4     3     4     1     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1];
bin_counts_b = [569   402   200   166   262    90    50    16    33    12     6    35    49     4    12     8     8     2     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1];

% Visualize the two "bin counts" vectors as bars:
bar(1:length(bin_counts_a),[bin_counts_a;bin_counts_b])
```

[image]

```
% Calculation of similarities
cosine_similarity  = 1 - pdist2(bin_counts_a,bin_counts_b,'cosine')
jaccard_similarity = 1 - pdist2(bin_counts_a,bin_counts_b,'jaccard')

% Output
cosine_similarity =

          0.95473215802008


jaccard_similarity =

        0.0769230769230769
```

**Question**

If the cosine similarity is close to 1, which means the two vectors are similar, shouldn't the jaccard similarity be closer to 1 as well?

Comment: For comparing histograms, [earth mover’s distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks a lot!! I did not know about this distance as measure of (dis)similarity of histograms.....I will try it for sure! ....but, just a question... in your opinion, why do you think this measure "would be more appropriate"? :-)

Comment: More appropriate than the Jaccard measure for sure. There are several measures commonly used to compare histograms, this is one of them. If you add a bit of noise to the data, then the histogram could see values move from one bin to its neighbor. These changes add a small amount to the earth mover’s distance, but might add a larger amount to something like cosine dissimilarity. The Kullback-Leibler divergence, mentioned in  Luis’ answer, is good too. Or you can use what they use in the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test: the largest difference between the two cumulative histograms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'jaccard'` measure, according to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), only considers the "percentage of nonzero coordinates that differ", but not *by how much* they differ.

For instance, assume `bin_counts_a` as in your example and

```
bin_counts_b = bin_counts_a + 1;
```

Then

```
>> cosine_similarity  = 1 - pdist2(bin_counts_a,bin_counts_b,'cosine')
cosine_similarity =
   0.999971577948095
```

is almost `1` as expected, because the bin counts are very similar. However,

```
>> jaccard_similarity = 1 - pdist2(bin_counts_a,bin_counts_b,'jaccard')
jaccard_similarity =
     0
```

gives `0` because each entry in `bin_counts_b` is (slightly) different from that in `bin_counts_a`.

For assessing the similarity between the histograms, `'cosine'` is probably a more meaningful option than `'jaccard'`. You may also want to consider the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), although it is not symmetric in the two distributions, and is not computed by `pdist2`.

Comment: many many thanks!! Great answer :-) Yes, I was thinking about the Kullback-Leibler divergence, but I was not sure if appropriate for this case.... I tried also the Chi-Square Test, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov one-sample test and the Log-likelihood to compare the histograms... but I have noticed that the Chi-Square Test is quite "strict" (when using the usual "significance level" of 0.05%), which means that the two histograms are considered different (indeed I got the rejection of the null hypothesis)... therefore, I was looking for less "strict" measure of similarity..

Comment: "Comprehensive Survey on Distance/Similarity
Measures between Probability Density Functions" by Sung-Hyuk Cha (http://www.fisica.edu.uy/~cris/teaching/Cha_pdf_distances_2007.pdf). This is a great review of (dis)similarity measures, but too many options and it is not easy to select the right ones for histograms :-) :-) Btw, I was thinking to focus on one type of measures, i.e. the "Table 4. Inner Product family".